# Support WeightV2 in a substrate chain?

Tags: weight, substrate-parachain-template, pallet-contracts

I started working from the [substrate-parachain-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template) and added the `pallet_contracts` to the runtime. When I open the Contracts UI, I'm getting the error message that states the node does not support WeightV2. I can't find any documentation related to this or how to modify the runtime to upgrade the weight. Here is the [parachain-contracts-node](https://github.com/ok-Alice/parachain-contracts-node).

[image: Unsupported node version WeightV2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your node is still using the old Weights format you still can deploy your smart contract using this link: https://weightv1--contracts-ui.netlify.app/

See this previous answer on StackExchange: [Problem adding a smart contract into a Substrate node](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/7059/2762)

If you want to update to Weights V2, check this old question on StackExchange: [Prepare pallets for Weights v2](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7926/prepare-pallets-for-weights-v2) or check how the weigths are calculate in the node-template: [benchmarking.rs](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node-template/pallets/template/src/benchmarking.rs)

Comment: I looked through all the links you sent me regarding upgrading a node to use WeightsV2, but have no idea what I need to change in my project. I have verified that I have the same runtime implementation as substrate-contracts-node related to weight configuration. Since you can configure each pallet with its own weight configuration, how does Contracts UI determine if you are using WeightsV2 or V1?

Comment: I check your code and I don't see the difference between the substrate-contracts-node https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L149. If you run the substrate-contracts-node instead of yours it works?

Comment: Yes substrate contracts node works with WeightV2. While we investigate, are there any more technical documentation related to pallets and how the runtime handles weights, and maybe how Contracts UI determines if the node uses WeightV2 or not?

Comment: It checks that the Weight type of your chain has the WeightsV2 format (It contains the proofSize filed), see the code: https://github.com/paritytech/contracts-ui/blob/master/src/ui/contexts/ApiContext.tsx#L46

Comment: Here is the error you see: https://github.com/paritytech/contracts-ui/blob/master/src/ui/components/common/NoticeBanner.tsx

Comment: To give more clarity on my current local development setup, I am running 2 validator nodes (alice & bob) for the polkadot relay chain and my parachain-contracts-node is running as a parachain which is connected to the relay chain. I started from the parachain template and added the `pallet_contracts` pallet to the runtime. 

When I access the Contracts UI platform and select the test network from the dropdown, I select "Local Node" which I presume is the parachain node.

Comment: I believe the "Local Node" is the one running in the port 9944, do you have the parachain running there?

Comment: No it isn't. 

```
./target/debug/parachain-template-node \
--alice \
--collator \
--force-authoring \
--chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json \
--base-path /tmp/parachain/alice \
--port 40333 \
--ws-port 8844 \
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain ../polkadot/raw-local-chainspec.json \
--port 30343 \
--ws-port 9977
```

It is the alice validator node running on port 9944 as relay chain node:
```
./target/release/polkadot \
--alice \
--validator \
--base-path /tmp/relay/alice \
--chain ./raw-local-chainspec.json \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9944
```

Comment: That's probably the issue! At the bottom of the page there is a settings button where you can change the endpoint. Go there an specify where your parachain is running

Comment: When I connect to port 8844, I get the following error message: "No accounts found". I tried connecting to port 9977, but I got the previous error unsupported WeigthV2.

Comment: My `node/src/chain_spec.rs` contains the configuration to add default accounts like Alice and Bob in the genesis state. So I'm not sure why I get the error "No accounts found".